# SQL query to calculate subtotal and grand total

Tags: sql

I have following sample data:

```
TimeSheetID RosterID    EmpID   RosterDate  StartTime   EndTime Total
       1         101    1001    2016-05-24  07:00   15:00   8
       2         101    1001    2016-05-24  16:00   21:00   5
       3         101    1002    2016-05-24  07:00   15:00   8
       4         101    1003    2016-05-24  07:00   15:00   8
       5         101    1001    2016-05-25  07:00   15:00   8
       6         101    1002    2016-05-25  07:00   15:00   8
       7         101    1002    2016-05-25  16:00   22:00   6
       8         101    1003    2016-05-25  07:00   15:00   8
       9         101    1001    2016-05-26  07:00   14:00   7
       10        101    1001    2016-05-26  15:00   21:00   6
       11        101    1002    2016-05-26  07:00   15:00   8
       12        101    1003    2016-05-26  07:00   15:00   8
       13        101    1001    2016-05-27  07:00   15:00   8
       14        101    1002    2016-05-27  07:00   15:00   8
       15        101    1003    2016-05-27  07:00   15:00   8
       16        101    1001    2016-05-28  07:00   15:00   8
       17        101    1002    2016-05-28  07:00   15:00   8
       18        101    1003    2016-05-28  07:00   15:00   8
       19        101    1001    2016-05-29  07:00   15:00   8
       20        101    1002    2016-05-29  07:00   15:00   8
       21        101    1003    2016-05-29  07:00   15:00   8
       22        102    1001    2016-05-30  07:00   15:00   8
```

I would like to produce:

```
ID       RosterID   EmpID   RosterDate  StartTime   EndTime Total
1        101        1001    2016-05-24  07:00        15:00  8
2        101        1001    2016-05-24  16:00        21:00  5
3        101        1001    2016-05-24  Null         Null   13
4        101        1002    2016-05-24  07:00        15:00  8
5        101        1003    2016-05-24  07:00        15:00  8
6        101        1001    2016-05-25  07:00        15:00  8
7        101        1002    2016-05-25  07:00        15:00  8
8        101        1002    2016-05-25  16:00        22:00  6
9        101        1002    2016-05-25  Null         Null   14
10       101        1003    2016-05-25  07:00        15:00  8
11       101        1001    2016-05-26  07:00        14:00  7
12       101        1001    2016-05-26  15:00        21:00  6
13       101        1001    2016-05-26  Null         Null   13
14       101        1002    2016-05-26  07:00        15:00  8
15       101        1003    2016-05-26  07:00        15:00  8
16       101        1001    2016-05-27  07:00        15:00  8
17       101        1002    2016-05-27  07:00        15:00  8
18       101        1003    2016-05-27  07:00        15:00  8
19       101        1001    2016-05-28  07:00        15:00  8
20       101        1002    2016-05-28  07:00        15:00  8
21       101        1003    2016-05-28  07:00        15:00  8
22       101        1001    2016-05-29  07:00        15:00  8
23       101        1002    2016-05-29  07:00        15:00  8
24       101        1003    2016-05-29  07:00        15:00  8
25       102        1001    2016-05-30  07:00        15:00  8
26       Total      Null    Null        Null         Null   168
```

I would like to get the sample output using SQL Query RollUp statement because performance is issue. As TimeSheet Table will have millions of records. Is there any other way of doing this writing procedure or function instead of views?
Thank you for your help in advance
Regards 
Ishwor

Comment: What sample data? What database engine? Do you have a schema?

Comment: You forgot to include your sample data

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't mix results with data in the same table. 
Also, if this is possible, I think it's not a good idea.

You can get the subtotal with a query similar to this:

```
select RosterID, EmpID, RosterDate, sum(Total) 
from tableRoster group by RosterID, EmpID, RosterDate;
```

The total is easier, you can get it with this:

```
select sum(Total) from tableRoster;
```

Comment: Thank you Jose, it looks simple but it did amazing work and good performance..... Thank you so much once more

Answer (score 0):

I tried to utilize your preferred method ... although there are probably some kinks to work out.  Apologies if it isn't working 100% as hoped for, but maybe you can take the below and modify it to your needs.

My suspicion is that including the start/end dates in there will result in trivial sub-groupings which can be ignored.  I realize not testing my solution fully is not ideal for this forum ... sorry for this ... just kind of whipped it up on a whim as a quick distraction from work.  Good luck to you.

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN (GROUPING(RosterID) = 1) THEN 'Total' 
      ELSE RosterID 
 END AS RosterID
,CASE WHEN (GROUPING(EmpID) = 1) AND (GROUPING(RosterID) = 1) THEN NULL 
      ELSE EmpID 
 END AS EmpID
,CASE WHEN (GROUPING(RosterDate) = 1) AND (GROUPING(RosterID) = 1) THEN NULL 
      ELSE RosterDate 
 END AS RosterDate
,CASE WHEN (GROUPING(RosterDate) = 1) THEN NULL 
      ELSE StartTime 
 END AS StartTime
,CASE WHEN (GROUPING(RosterDate) = 1) THEN NULL 
      ELSE EndTime 
 END AS EndTime
,Sum(Total) AS Total
FROM Table a
GROUP BY 
 ROLLUP(RosterID ,RosterDate ,EmpID ,StartTime ,EndTime)
ORDER BY
 RosterID, RosterDate, EmpID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried to resolve with basic loop as below

-- ASSUMED THAT DATA IS INSERTED INTO Roster TABLE 
-- STP_01: BY SEEING DATA COLUMNS ARE CREATED AS BELOW
CREATE TABLE Roster(TimeSheetID INT IDENTITY(1,1),RosterID INT ,EmpID INT , RosterDate DATE ,StartTime TIME, EndTime TIME, Total INT)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Roster ON
GO

-- STP_02:INSERTING PROVIDED DATA AS BELOW
INSERT INTO Roster(TimeSheetID,RosterID,EmpID,RosterDate,StartTime,EndTime,Total)
VALUES(1 ,101,1001,'2016-05-24','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(2 ,101,1001,'2016-05-24','16:00', '21:00', 5),
(3 ,101,1002,'2016-05-24','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(4 ,101,1003,'2016-05-24','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(5 ,101,1001,'2016-05-25','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(6 ,101,1002,'2016-05-25','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(7 ,101,1002,'2016-05-25','16:00', '22:00', 6),
(8 ,101,1003,'2016-05-25','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(9 ,101,1001,'2016-05-26','07:00', '14:00', 7),
(10,101,1001,'2016-05-26','15:00', '21:00', 6),
(11,101,1002,'2016-05-26','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(12,101,1003,'2016-05-26','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(13,101,1001,'2016-05-27','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(14,101,1002,'2016-05-27','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(15,101,1003,'2016-05-27','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(16,101,1001,'2016-05-28','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(17,101,1002,'2016-05-28','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(18,101,1003,'2016-05-28','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(19,101,1001,'2016-05-29','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(20,101,1002,'2016-05-29','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(21,101,1003,'2016-05-29','07:00', '15:00', 8),
(22,102,1001,'2016-05-30','07:00', '15:00', 8)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Roster OFF
GO

-- STP_03:CREATING Roster_1 TABLE TO INSERT PROCESSED DATA - NOT TOUCHING ORIGINAL TABLE
-- DROP TABLE Roster_1
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roster_1](
    [TimeSheetID] [int] NULL,
    [RosterID] [varchar](15) NULL,  -- CHANGED TO VARCHAR(15) TO PROVIDE GrpToal/GndTotal
    [EmpID] [varchar](15) NULL,     -- CHANGED TO VARCHAR(15) TO PROVIDE GrpToal/GndTotal
    [RosterDate] [date] NULL,
    [StartTime] [time](7) NULL,
    [EndTime] [time](7) NULL,
    [Total] [int] NULL
) 

-- STP_04: SOME VARIABLES TO PROCESS LOOP
DECLARE @MinRosterDate DATE,@MaxRosterDate DATE,@MinEmpId INT,@MaxEmpID INT,@kMinEmpId INT
SELECT 
        @MinRosterDate = MIN(RosterDate),   -- 2016-05-24
        @MaxRosterDate = MAX(RosterDate),   -- 2016-05-30
        @MinEmpId = MIN(EmpID),             -- 1001
        @MaxEmpID = MAX(EmpID)              -- 1003
FROM Roster

-- STP_05: RE-RUNNABLE
TRUNCATE TABLE Roster_1

SET @kMinEmpId  = @MinEmpId -- RESERVING THIS VALUE

-- STEP_06: ENTERING LOOP
WHILE (@MinRosterDate<= @MaxRosterDate)     -- OUTER LOOP
BEGIN
    WHILE(@MinEmpId <= @MaxEmpID)           -- INNER LOOP FOR ALL EMPID WORKED DURING THIS TIME FRAME
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Roster WHERE RosterDate = @MinRosterDate AND EmpID = @MinEmpId) -- CHECKING WHETHER DATA EXISTS
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Roster_1    
            SELECT TimeSheetID,CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),RosterID),CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),EmpID),RosterDate,StartTime,EndTime,Total FROM Roster WHERE RosterDate = @MinRosterDate AND EmpID = @MinEmpId
            UNION
            SELECT null,'GrpTotalByEmpID',@MinEmpId,@MinRosterDate,null,null,SUM(Total)FROM Roster WHERE RosterDate = @MinRosterDate AND EmpID = @MinEmpId
        END 

        SET @MinEmpId = @MinEmpId + 1 -- BREAKING INNER LOOP
    END

    IF(@MinEmpId > @MaxEmpId)        -- RESTARING FROM FIRST EmpID
        SET @MinEmpId = @kMinEmpId

    INSERT INTO Roster_1
    SELECT null,null,'GrpTotalByDate',@MinRosterDate,null,null,SUM(Total) from Roster_1 where RosterID = 'GrpTotalByEmpID' and RosterDate = @MinRosterDate

    IF(@MinRosterDate = @MaxRosterDate)     -- CALCULATING Grand Total
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Roster_1
        SELECT null,'GrandTotal',null,null,null,null,SUM(Total) FROM Roster_1 WHERE TimeSheetID IS NULL AND EmpID = 'GrpTotalByDate'
    END

    SET @MinRosterDate = DATEADD(DD,1, @MinRosterDate) -- BREAKING OUTER LOOP

END

-- STP_07: READING PROCESSED DATA
SELECT * FROM Roster_1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the following [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question so you get better answers.